# Inline SVG via URI

Tags: css, svg, sass, uri, gulp-sass

I am trying to use data URI's for my SVG images, within css. The basic approach is to set the full data URI to `=` the value of the background property for the css class.

```
.bg {
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg ...> ... </svg>');
}
```

My question is: how can I break the data URI value into a separate file, and reference that file within my css class. Goal: separate all data URI's from base styles so that they do not make the css ridiculously long.

Have never used URI's to implement SVG's so am also open to *any* ideas anyone may have re: implementation of SVG's through URI. Thanks a bunch! :)

P.S. If there is a good way to automate this, I am using gulp and bootstrap sass for this project.

Comment: You'd save the data uri as a file and then reference it. Of course it's no longer a data URI at that point, but merely a URI.

Comment: This is super basic, but how would you reference the file. What extension would you give to the file? How might I reference just one SVG within said file?

Comment: Depends where you put it. The obvious extension would be .svg wouldn't it? I don't really understand the last question.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use grunt-grunticon which produces css classes for you with fallback to png if needed. Then you can use scss or sass to @extend the icon in a way that you would like to use it. For instance `@extend .icon-undo;`

Hope this helps. Good luck.